# How to serialize complex types using Microsoft Avro library

Tags: azure, hadoop, serialization, avro

I am trying to serialize generic records (expressed as JSON strings) as avro objects using the `Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro` library.

I've been following the tutorial for Generic Records [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-dotnet-avro-serialization). However, the records I am trying to serialize as more complex than the sample code provided by Microsoft (Location), with nested properties inside the JSON.

Here is a sample of a record I want to serialize in Avro:

`{
    "deviceId": "UnitTestDevice01",
    "serializationFormat": "avro",
    "messageType": "state",
    "messageVersion": "avrov2.0",
    "arrayProp": [
        {
            "itemProp1": "arrayValue1",
            "itemProp2": "arrayValue2"
        },
        {
            "itemProp1": "arrayValue3",
            "itemProp2": "arrayValue4"
        }
    ]
}`

For info, here is the Avro schema I can extract:

`{
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "xxx.avro",
    "name": "MachineModel",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "deviceId",
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    }, {
        "name": "serializationFormat",
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    }, {
        "name": "messageType",
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    }, {
        "name": "messageVersion",
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    }, {
        "name": "array",
        "type": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "array_record",
                "fields": [{
                    "name": "arrayProp1",
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                }, {
                    "name": "arrayProp2",
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
}`

I have managed to extract the correct schema for this object, but I can't get the code right to take the schema and create a correct Avro record.

Can someone provide some pointers on how I can use the `AvroSerializer` or `AvroContainer` classes to produce a valid avro object using this json payload and this avro schema? The sample from Microsoft are quite simple to work with complex objects and I have not been able to find relevant samples online either.

Comment: one would think someone would have an answer to that :/